# Excel CONCATENATE function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What am I doing wrong here?
I've tried using the CONCAT and CONCATENATE function and I keep getting this error.
I would like the result to be 'text1 hello'

[image]

Comment: Do you normally use a comma as the list separator? Does `=A1&" hello"` work?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I feel dumb. I'm using a German keyboard and the formula separator is semi-colon, not comma :/